# Is it possible to use S3 bucket logs as a hack for privacy oriented/basic analytics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, analytics

I am looking for a simple, dirt cheap way to do some basic analytics for my site. I really mean basic and something that respects users privacy + does not use cookies.

I was wondering, would it make sense to:
- just have an s3 bucket with logging enabled
- place a tiny image there
- link to the image from my site

Would the requests for that image get logged to the logs?

I am interested mostly in a ballpark of the page views. I don't care about real-time or same day log delivery (I am most likely to check this one a month). The logs seem to have some nice details like IP address, which can be used for guess-estimating the countries.

However, my question is that amazon states that they do "A Best Effort Server Log Delivery".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

Based on experience:
- how good is this best effort and how consistent?
- What are the odds that this approach works?

Thank you for entertaining the silly idea :)

Comment: If you want a "cheap way to do some basic analytics for your site", just use Google Analytics.

Comment: I don't want to keep participating in the tracking people economy and the bad data culture. Also, I am trying to do a non Javascript solution if possible